# Bernoulli process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $X_t$ be a stochastic process such that:

$X_t \sim \left\{ \matrix{Ber(0,75) \text{ if } X_{t-1} = 1\\ 
Ber(0,25) \text{ if } X_{t-1} = 0
}\right.$

Let $t = 0$ be the initial step and let us fix the initial state to $1$.

What appends when $t$ goes to infinity?

I think the process becomes $Ber(0,5)$. Is it right?

Can you give a hint to solve the exercise?

Thank you very much!

Comment: *Hint.* You can realize the law of $(X_n:n\geq0)$ as $$X_n =\frac{Z_1\cdots Z_n +1}{2}$$where $Z_n$ are i.i.d. and $P(Z_n=1)=3/4$ and $P(Z_n=-1)=1/4$. So $$P(X_n=1)=P(\text{even number of $Z_1,\cdots,Z_n$ are $-1$})$$which can be explicitly computed using the binomial distribution: $P(X_n=1)=\frac{1+2^{-n}}{2}$. Or, since $(X_n)$ is an irreducible aperiodic Markov chain on a finit state space, it converges in distribution to its unique statuonary distribution, which is $\operatorname{Bernoulli}(1/2)$.

Comment: Hi Sangchul, thank for your hint!
I'll try tomorrow!